# How widely used is Mono for real-world applications?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Followup question to comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736101/what-applications-had-better-be-developed-in-c-over-c-in-todays-business)

My impression had been that Mono is a science project.  Is that inaccurate?  Extra credit for recounting personal usage.

Comment: Me too.  I hear they're working on sore throats.

Comment: This should be a CW. At least.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

completely inaccurate.

mono is an implementation of a spec (just like .net is another implementation). its extremely complete and very usable.

I'm working on an asp.net mvc project that's being written in monodevelop and running in xsp2 (for now. I will probably set up an apache with mod_mono).

I've been a .net/mono guy for about 5-6 years and here are some things I've worked on:

- instrumentation devices that work over gpib/serial/usb to do fiberoptics testing, moving robot arms, etc
- networking tools
- projects when I was in school in command line, AND in windows forms.
- personal projects
- image processing tools
- monotouch to write iphone apps

I also use monodevelop as my main c# development platform. I do have visual studio 2008, but I prefer monodevelop as its lighter and runs on my mac.

Comment: I am accepting this as nobody else seems to have actually used it.

Answer (score 20):

> My impression had been that Mono is a
>   science project. Is that inaccurate?

That is correct.  A simple [Wikipedia search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) gives details on the Mono project:

"Mono is a project created as an entry for Paul Revere High School's 2005 Science Fair, located on the west side of Boston.  Although judges responded favorably to the project, it did not win or place in the fair.  Its creator, Miguel de Icaza, received a B+ for his entry."

Comment: I think you missed the responder's bone-dry humour.  I don't think -1 is deserved.

Comment: it's at time like these that i remember why i wanted the <sarcasm></sarcasm> tags to be part of html...

Answer (score 10):

Sure it's a science project. Just like Lisp, the Universal Turing Machine, REST, HTTP 1.1, google, and the basic idea that if we can treat functions as data and vice-versa then it should be possible to create programmable computing machines. Such machines could almost be called "computers" because they would be able to do much the same jobs as computers - the people hired in corporations and govt. departments to do mathematical calculations. Perhaps they'd even open up possibilities of doing things that a team of clerks with slide-rules couldn't do.

Starting as a science project doesn't mean the most it can ever achieve is a blue ribbon and an A+.

Comment: great comment... I wish I could give more than +1

Answer (score 5):

This page on the Mono site lists the applications published using Mono:

http://www.mono-project.com/Software

Some quite well-known ones include Unity3D, SourceGear Vault and Sims3.

Answer (score 5):

I built a javascript interpreter/compiler with F# on an Ubuntu workstation and compiled it with Mono!  Mono saved me from using Windows to develop my application.

Comment: Now that's taking things to the limit, you are my geek of the week! +1!

Answer (score 2):

Mono is not a science project and is used in many real-world applications.

It *is* an implementation of the [Common Language Infrastructure](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) ECMA standard.

See [this list](http://mono-project.com/Software) on the mono site.

It is used by wikis, SCMs, games, game development environments and many online applications.

Answer (score 2):

The best example for me is Unity, it uses Mono/C# as it's scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is used in a wide of of industries. From gaming (second life) to the embedded industrie.
Maybe it started as a science project, mono is doing it good and will be doing it good (a part is that there has not to be paid license money for some part of the use of it (not embedded part although where there has to be paid fees). Probelley some goodscentance to end: the makers of google started that as a university project too.

So to be answer quick, NO

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys! Don't forget [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/gallery.aspx)!! Check the screenshots in the gallery. There are other projects but we do the best graphics :P

Some of our biggest production servers on big, big companies run Mono/Linux. And some even Mono/Solaris... And we rely on Mono for Mac too, of course.