# Any open source C#/Mono Projects?

Tags: c#, open-source, mono

Could someone please give good samples of opensource `C# / Mono` projects, if possible with tests for `xUnit` / any other testing framework.

*This might also be the source code in `C#` that you've enjoyed the most.*

For example, in `C++` I could probably name any library from `boost sandbox` or the `Qt` framework as an example of well-written and maintained projects (something you really enjoy studying).

Thank you.

*If this is a duplicate, please point it out. I didn't find any topics with the same question, but I really wish to :)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These come to mind quickly. I have hacked on two of them myself.

- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) - Cross-platform, extensible IDE supporting C#, among other languages.
- [Banshee](http://banshee.fm) - Cross-platform, extensible media library manager/player. Similar to iTunes in some respects.
- [F-Spot](http://f-spot.org/) - Cross-platform, extensible photo manipulator and library manager.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736243/how-widely-used-is-mono-for-real-world-applications) about real-world Mono usage might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few at [mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com/Software)